# Xamarin C# Visual Studio - Automated Mailto - send email to user in code behind?

Tags: c#, email, xamarin, mailto

I've updated my plist to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes value: mailto and I still receieve the error:

-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "mailto:" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme mailto"

Any advice on this? I'd like an email I've constructed to be sent to the user on click.

`code`
public async Task SendEmail(string body, List recipient)
{
try
{
var message = new EmailMessage
{
Subject = "Password Reset",
Body = body,
To = recipient,
//Cc = ccRecipients,
//Bcc = bccRecipients
};
await Email.ComposeAsync(message);
}
catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fbsEx)
{
// Email is not supported on this device
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
// Some other exception occurred
}
}

`code`

Comment: is this a compiler error or a runtime exception?  What are you doing that generates it?

Comment: What is in the plist now?

Comment: Also note, I think it will only work on a real device, not in the simulator.

Comment: You are correct, it was because I wasn't deploying to my device however the results wasn't what I was expecting, it opened my mail to send an email but what I want it to do is just send an email as I am working on password reset... Any advice on this?

Comment: You can raise a new issue and attach a new description